# On Java7's diamond, clarification needed

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double brace initialisation (anonymous inner class) with diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773733/double-brace-initialisation-anonymous-inner-class-with-diamond-operator)

Using Java 7, why is the following a problem

```
final List<String> a = new ArrayList<>() {
    {
        add("word");
    }
};
```

Explicit type declaration is needed as in

```
final List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        add("word");
    }
};
```

Comment: Diamond for anonymous class is not supported due to some technicality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214069/compile-error-cannot-be-used-with-anonymous-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, In general, Java avoids type inference.

In any case, the `<>` only works when the compiler doesn't need to know which generic type was used. In the case of the anonymous classes, the actual type needs to be provided as the compiler doesn't infer the type.

Effectively `<>` turns off the type checking, rather than providing type inference. An anonymous class stores the actual generic type and so you have to provide it.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>()
```

is rather like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<String> a = new ArrayList()
```

but for an anonymous subclass the compiler needs to give it a generic type.

Comment: +1 Hm, I was absolutely convinced `<>` was about inference! The way it works for a factory method.

Comment: diamond isn't raw typing. it does type inference and type checking.

Comment: @irreputable Can you give an example where `<>` checks something or infers the type?

Comment: it becomes more obvious if the type variable has bounds. e.g. if we have `class NumList<T extends Number> extends ArrayList<T>{}`, then `List<String> list = new NumList<>();` won't compile, because inference fails. but raw typing works: `List<String> list = new NumList();`